# Can I load Nib's in another thread? (iPhone dev)

Tags: iphone, multithreading, cocoa-touch, nib

At the moment, I'm getting data for the next view from the server.
While this goes on, I am showing the user a loading indicator.
After the data have been loaded, the main thread gets notified and loads the nib for the new view.

My question is:
Because I already have this loading mechanism, can I safely load the nib's in the working thread and just push them from within the main thread?

Comment: Your description is not really clear, but I guess your data downloading is made by another thread. This thread is calling the main thread when the download has finished. I'm right ?

Comment: Yes you are right. Sorry about being unclear

Answer (score 1):

`UIKit` is not thread safe, so I suspect it should be pretty unsafe loading the nib in a secondary thread. Just loading the nib in a UIViewController and displaying it from the main thread could work for you and may break elsewhere.

I suppose you know about `performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone` to dispatch a method from a secondary thread to the main thread. You could try and use this from your secondary thread when you want to load the nib.

EDIT:

what about *preloading* the nib while the working thread is retrieving the data, so that when the working thread has done, the main thread has only to *display* the nib views?

Comment: This would do the trick, but while main thread loads the nib, the loading indicator will stop.